# Como tocar uma instância de objeto audio no Safari?

Tags: javascript

Como faço para uma instância de audio tocar no Safari?

```
var som = new Audio("http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3");

function tocar() {
   this.play();
}
som.addEventListener('canplay', tocar, false);
```

Veja que [neste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsuket/jTh3v/) ele não funciona no Safari.

Comment: Nessa resposta, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31777081/4312593, é comentando a possibilidade de desabilitar a reprodução automática.

Comment: Coloque um texto entre as tags `<audio ...>Não suportado</audio>`... se o texto for exibido, a tag não é compatível com o navegador. Aí não há nada que se possa fazer, exceto outra forma de incorporar som nesse navegador.

Comment: O teu jsFiddle funciona para mim no Safari...

Comment: Sim, funciona, porém ele demora a carregar.